# Geo fencing for iOS

Tags: swift, google-maps, geolocation, geofencing

I just wanted to enable only particular height-lighted country from entire google map to let the user select any location just like Android.

I referred so many link but the only shape I could monitor is circular not country shape.

I have a string of lat longs of whole country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I referred so many link but the only shape I could monitor is circular not country shape.

Unfortunately, iOS currently only lets you monitor circular regions, which means that you'll need to do some more work to monitor arbitrary-shaped regions. You'll want to do something like:

1. Create a circular region that's tangent to the nearest border and start monitoring it.
2. When you get a notification that the user has moved outside the region, check to see whether they've crossed the border. If not, remove the current region and go to step 1.